# How can I get the current date in an Azure Pipeline YAML file to use ase a variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to inject a useful version number into my ASP Core application which I'm building and deploying using an Azure DevOps pipeline.

```
- script: dotnet publish -c $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=2022.06.21 -p:SourceRevisionId=$(Build.SourceVersion)
```

But I cannot for the life of me work out how to get the date into a variable where I can actually use it. Which is pretty remarkable really since the current date (with some other fluff appended) is what DevOps itself uses for the default build number.

The documentation is horrendous. How do I do this?

Comment: There is no predefined variable containing the current date, but you can add a custom script to get the current date (i.e. with PowerShell), and write it to an own variable, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) for more detail

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the [`format` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format) you can transform the `pipeline.startTime` into a formatted date. In your case, define the variable like the following:

```yaml
variables:
  currentDate: $[ format('{0:yyyy}.{0:MM}.{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
```

Then use the variable like the following:

```
- script: dotnet publish -c $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(currentDate) -p:SourceRevisionId=$(Build.SourceVersion)
```

Comment: This sorted me out, although I found the syntax in your answer resulted in a format error, the following expression though did work. currentDate: $[format('{0:yyyy}.{0:MM}.{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime)]

Comment: @Neutrino thanks for sorting this out, I did not test this. Will update the answer.

Comment: Note that this doesn't appear to be the actual pipeline start time, but when the agent started. Meaning it will give you different results per job. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pipelinestarttime-is-not-consistent-in-a-pipeline/1558186

Comment: Can you add hours and minutes too? - "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: @marko sure, just check the doc I linked. You can use any .NET date format specifiers. For hours and minutes you can use `HH:mm`