# Azure DevOps yaml - Get current date with MMM (month short name)

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use a date variable/param in an Azure DevOps yaml for a pipeline and i am having difficulty in finding a way to get the month short name without reinventing the wheel.

I have found this question here: [How can I get the current date in an Azure Pipeline YAML file to use ase a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699533/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-in-an-azure-pipeline-yaml-file-to-use-ase-a-varia)

so i got the format and changed it to use "MMM" instead of "MM" like so

```
variables:
  currentDate: $[ format('{0:yyyy}.{0:MMM}.{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
```

but this is throwing an error when i execute it:

> The format specifiers 'MMM' are not valid for objects of type 'DateTime'

My expectation would be to have the formatting be something like 25.Dec.2024 - just a display thing, i am using that date to pass on to an app execution as a string run argument, example:

```
variables:
  currentDate: $[ format('{0:yyyy}.{0:MM}.{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
  executionTitle: "My Test Execution $(currentDate)"
```

Comment: Hi, it fails because `MMM` is not valid input for _months_ using the `format` expression in Azure Pipelines.   

It will work with single `M` and give: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12`  
It will work with dual `MM` and give: `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12`  
If you feel like this answer does not provide sufficient answer, please elaborate on why you want to use triple `MMM`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have updated my question to reflect this, i'm looking to get month formated like Jan, Feb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, Azure DevOps does not allow you to provide such a format. It is possible to change the formatting by custom process, but this is a workaround. In the case of the given example, the pipeline becomes more complicated and also the formatting is platform-dependent (if you are not using cross-platform tools). Simpler version - works with Powershell tasks:

```
trigger: 
  - '*'

pool: linux

variables:
  time: $[ format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
  pwsh_time: $(Get-Date -Date $(time) -Format yyyy.MMM.dd)
steps:
  - pwsh: echo $(var1)
  - bash: echo $(var1) //error: line 1: Get-Date: command not found
```

This is modified version with output variables that solves above problem:

```
trigger: 
  - '*'

pool: linux

variables:
  time: $[ format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
  pwsh_time: $(Get-Date -Date $(time) -Format yyyy.MMM.dd)

jobs:
- job: Prep
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=out;isoutput=true]$(pwsh_time)"
    name: format_time
- job: B
  dependsOn: Prep
  variables:
    formated_time: $[ dependencies.Prep.outputs['format_time.out'] ]  
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo $(formated_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Expressions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format),

> Uses [.NET custom date and time format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for date formatting (`yyyy`, `yy`, `MM`, `M`, `dd`, `d`, `HH`, `H`, `m`, `mm`, `ss`, `s`, `f`, `ff`, `ffff`, `K`)

Therefore, the format specifiers 'MMM' are not valid for objects of type 'DateTime'

Not sure why you would like to use `MMM`, but here is a workaround for your reference, given `MMM` output will always begin with `0`.

```
variables:
  currentDate: $[ format('{0:yyyy}.0{0:MM}.{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]

steps:
- script: 
    echo $(currentDate)
```

[image]

Comment: i was looking to obtain the month formated like Jan, Feb, Mar etc. i may have asked it wrong or didnt' understand the code in the question i linked. sorry, not my area

Comment: Hi @AndreiB, Based on your update, MarcinSlowikowski has shared a workaround - sample pipeline to use PowerShell script to set the expected date format and [define output variables across different jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs). There is no built-in function/expression in a YAML pipeline but hope Marcin's workaround can meet your requirement. Thanks for the sharing.